# Linq Execute query InvalidOperationException

Tags: mysql, wpf, vb.net, linq

I am trying to delete some rows in a couple of tables and when I try to execute this I get an InvalidOperationException: **The required column 'id' does not exist in the results.**

The values that I am trying to look up and delete have been added to lists before this function is called.

```
    For Each dh In DHeadList
        For Each dl In DLineList
            Dim dlparam() = {dh.DHeadID}
            Dim dlQuery As String = "DELETE From dbo.DLine WHERE DHeadId={0}"
            db.ExecuteQuery(Of DLine)(dlQuery, dlparam)
        Next
        Dim dhparam() = {dh.DHeadID}
        Dim dhQuery As String = "DELETE FROM dbo.DHead WHERE id ={0}"
        db.ExecuteQuery(Of DHead)(dhQuery, dhparam)
    Next
```

I have no idea why the error says 'id' because this actually errors inside the nested for loop where I am looking at the **DLineList**. So I am not looking at the id of the **Dhead** table until after all records from **DLine** are deleted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which type is `db` ? Does it have a `.ExecuteNonQuery()` function? Since Delete,Update,Insert are handled differently than Selects.

Comment: No it has `.ExecuteQuery` and `.ExecuteQuery(Of)`

Comment: I repeat myself: which type is db ?

Comment: Sorry, its a Data context of an SQL database `Dim db = New CASADataContext()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.ExecuteQuery(Of DHead)(dhQuery, dhparam) 
db.ExecuteQuery(Of DLine)(dlQuery, dlparam)
```

One of these two statements is root cause, because you are asking for a strong type (sql server parsed) result set, the message is telling us that in one of those two classes it cannot find the ID field which is in the database to stuff the value.  Add the ID field to one or both of those classes and you should be set.